# Changepoint method returning last point of segment

Tags: r

The [documentation of the changepoint package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/changepoint.pdf) says that *a changepoint is denoted as the first observation of the new segment / regime*. However, when I try to detect the changepoints in this very simple example, it gives me the *last* observation of the segment:

```
library(changepoint)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10)
res <- cpt.meanvar(x, class=TRUE, method="PELT")

bp <- cpts(res)
# bp contains the point 5
colors <- rep("black", length(x))
colors[bp] <- 'red'
plot(x, col=colors, pch=19, cex=1)
```

[image]

Shouldn't it return the 6th instead of the 5th?

Comment: This might be a documentation bug or our insufficient understanding how a "new segment / regime" is defined. If you have time you could study the references (you should probably do that anyway if you are using this method), but I would ask the package maintainer.

Comment: In my package `Rbeast,`  I defined the first observation of a new segment rather than the last point of a previous segment as the changepoint: `library(Rbeast)`; `plot(beast( c(1,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10), season='none'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roland highlighted this is a documentation bug.  This has been reported here:
https://github.com/rkillick/changepoint/issues/13
and is fixed in the github version. It will be pushed to CRAN with the next release.

This has been an open issue on StackOverflow for a long time, if alberto had reported this to the maintainer as Roland suggested i'm sure it would have been fixed sooner.  A lesson to us all.

Comment: Oups, sorry about that, I must have moved on to something else and forgot about that.

Comment: No problem, these things happen.  Not meant as a dig, just for anyone reading this thread in the future.